# Seg fault after for loop completes

Tags: c

Trying to check stdin args for illegal characters (colon, fullstop and comma). 
Using strchr. If it finds an illegal char in the args it exits as I'd expect. If all the input is okay then it throws back a seg fault (after checking all the args). Doesn't leave the for loop

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for(int i=0; i<=argc; i++) {
        const char colon = ':';
        const char stop = '.';
        const char comma = ',';
        char *a, *b, *c;
        a = strchr(argv[i], colon);
        b = strchr(argv[i], stop);
        c = strchr(argv[i], comma);

        if (a != NULL || b != NULL || c != NULL) {
            printf("found invalid char\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=1; i < argc; i++) {`  You have one too many iterations. And `argv[0]` is the path of the running program. Also, command line args have nothing to do with `stdin`.

Comment: If your question is "how do you debug a seg fault", you should tell us more about your platform and what debugger you like to use. Getting an explanation for the bug in your code won't help you nearly as much as learning how to debug problems of this type.

Answer (score 4):

`argv` goes from `0` to `argc - 1`.

Therefore, your loop condition:

```
i<=argc
```

is wrong by one. It will access invalid memory which will trigger a segfault.